# Code of CURL of Gemini AI API in C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, curl, artificial-intelligence, google-gemini

I am developing a window app in c# .net framework about making ai using Google Gemini API. And I read the documentation of google gemini api over 10 times in [CURL](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/rest_quickstart). With some help of ChatGPT, I wrote some codes in C#. And here what is looks like:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KJAI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userInput = textBox1.Text;

            string output = await SendRequestAndGetResponse(userInput);

            output = output.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine)
                           .Replace("\n", "")
                           .Replace("**", "");

            richTextBox1.Text = output;
        }

        private async Task<string> SendRequestAndGetResponse(string userInput)
        {
            string jsonBody = $@"{{
                ""contents"": [
                    {{
                        ""role"": """",
                        ""parts"": [
                            {{
                                ""text"": ""{userInput}""
                            }}
                        ]
                    }}
                ],
                ""generationConfig"": {{
                    ""temperature"": 0.9,
                    ""topK"": 50,
                    ""topP"": 0.95,
                    ""maxOutputTokens"": 4096,
                    ""stopSequences"": []
                }},
                ""safetySettings"": [

                ]
            }}";

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.0-pro:generateContent?key={apiKey}");
            request.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseBody.Substring(responseBody.IndexOf("\"text\": \"") + 9, responseBody.IndexOf("\"", responseBody.IndexOf("\"text\": \"") + 10) - responseBody.IndexOf("\"text\": \"") - 9);
            }
            else
            {
                return $"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to make Gemini able to remember the previous conversation between an user and the ai, but I have no idea how to do this. Anyone who have ideas?

I tried my best to build chat history between user and ai and make it into dictionary form, but I failed. It is important to able ai to access and remember the conversation they had.

Comment: have you checked this https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/rest_quickstart#multi-turn_conversations_chat

Comment: Yes. I did check. However, I am very stupid so I didn't understand anything and how does it relate to my c# project. haha...

Comment: Well you said you are using google Gemini api thats the Gemini docs. if your looking for an official Gemini library for .net then your not going to find one.  You will have to check the link i gave you which shows how the objects need to look.   Not sure I understand what is funny about my answer sorry just trying to help.

Comment: Review the link that Linda provided. Notice the `contents` section and how multiple `role/parts` are provided. That is how you provide history. Note: at this time use gemini-pro and text-only input for chat use cases. I do not recommend including API Keys as request query parameters. Instead use a Google reserved header: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-goog-api-key", api_key);`.